# Flutter text widget: achieve horizontal vertical align; left-align horizontal

Tags: flutter

Good evening Stack Overflow.

Any advances on this Flutter code to achieve vertically-centered, but left-aligned text, in a simple full width container?

I found I had to fall back on making a secondary wrapper column around the text, and set BOTH mainAxisAlignment.center (for horizontal centering) and crossAxisalignment.start (to get left alignment).

I don;t want to set the Main column's axis alignments, as there will be other text widgets with different text alignments.

For the wrapper column I made it seems I can't just set mainAxisAlignment.center (for horizontal center) and then force textAlign.left in the Text widget itself. Surprised by that.

Anyway, the below code works, but surely there's a more efficient way?

```
body: SafeArea(
  child: Column(  //<-MAIN column for everything on the page 
    children: <widget> [
      // A container for my text widget
      Container(
      height: 50;
      width: double.infinity,
       Child: Column(    //<- had to make another wrapper column.
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          Children: [
           Text('mytext')
           ]
       ),
      ) //container
     ] //children
 )) //Main column and SafeArea
```

Cheers.

Comment: Have you looked into `TextStyle` Widget?

Comment: TextStyle will do fontsize, color etc, but no alignment features.

TextAlign can align text left or right (within the container) but it cant' do vertical alignment simultaneously - as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your `Text` Widget in an `Align` Widget and set the alignment to `centerLeft`

Comment: Nice! Thank you Omar.

Comment: Child: Align( 
           alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,  
           Child: Text('mytext')
       ),

Works perfect, way more efficient.